# Can't port forward in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Trying to port forward  the neo4j helm chart (stable/neo4j) using the command:

```
kubectl port-forward svc/neo-helm-neo4j 7474:7474
```

However it then gave me the following when I try and hit it from `localhost:7474`.

```
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:7474 -> 7474                                                                                                                                   
Forwarding from [::1]:7474 -> 7474                                                                                                                                       
Handling connection for 7474                                                                                                                                             
E0812 16:19:07.312926   26275 portforward.go:400] an error occurred forwarding 7474 -> 7474: error forwarding port 7474 to pod   b0b0e55e1bcc82090308a82666aa103bb65a48cc34
79ecdb1d51cb0861ddd131, uid : exit status 1: 2019/08/12 15:19:07 socat[50406] E connect(17, AF=2 127.0.0.1:7474, 16): Connection refused
```

The pods are up and available and the get svc yields

```
NAME                     TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
kubernetes               ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP    10d
neo-helm-neo4j           ClusterIP   None            <none>        7474/TCP   143m
```

I don't know what I'm missing out on. The fact that the service has no cluster-ip is odd; I would expect there to be one as it is a service. However I'm new to k8s, so this may all be very obviously wrong.

Comment: please check `kubectl describe pod <pod name>` and also check the logs of pod.

Comment: Do you mean the service? The service exposes  a route to three stateful sets, so which pod would you be interested in?

Comment: all in ready state ? are you using socket or anything?

Comment: please share the kubectl describe pod output.

Comment: I have checked the repo of the helm chart and the service neo-helm-neo4j is headless, which means it doesn't have a clusterIP. However the port-forward still should have worked. Can you try `kubectl get statefulset` and `kubectl port-forward {name of one of neo4j's statefulsets} 7474:7474`

Answer (score 0):

You can port forward pods. Normally this would create problems with scaled deployments but in this case it is headless service. This means neo4j handles master-slave communication itself. You can port forward master pod, please check this reference: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/#forward-a-local-port-to-a-port-on-the-pod